# How to set up a website contact form to send emails

Tags: php, html, web

i am working on my website and I have a little issue 
I want the contact form to send me information a user posts as an email
I did a little research and this cant be done with html or javascript but can be done with php
I got a few php code snippets online and put on the website but it did not work and I can't really troubleshoot it since I don't know php.. I need some help I put the link to the github repo for the site I wont mind if anyone takes a look and helps with a solution the contact form is on the store.html page and the php file handling the mail request is called mail_handler.php
thanks a lot 
Much appreciated
https://github.com/ekanime/trickbeats.git

Comment: Can you include logs and errors that you are being returned?

Comment: This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405...Thats the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#contactForm').on('submit', submitForm); // step 1: connect submit action to button
function submitForm() {
    // step 2: get data from input fields
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();


    // check if data is present
    console.log(name, email, message);

    // step 3: send data to contact form mailer
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://example.com/api/contact.php', //your API, If you do not have one, no data will sent
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'to_email': 'your.email@example.com',
            'from_fname': fname,
            'from_email': email,
            'message': message
        },
        'success': formSuccess,
        'error': formError
    });
    return false;//inorder not to referesh the page.
}
// step 4: handle response (success or error)
function formSuccess(result) {
    if (result.error) { // there was an error
        alert(result.error);
    } else { // everything went well
        alert(result.response);
        $("#contactForm")[0].reset(); //instead of saying getElementById
        // clear input fields
    }
}
// step 5: handle error
function formError(xhr, status, error) {
    alert("There has been an error. Please retry");
}
```

**Check your code, you must change "lname" to "email"**
[image]

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late Comment I went to finish other parts of the website before coming back to this.. I did what you instructed but I still have the error I have added a snap shot of the error code to the git hub repo..Im still new to web dev so I these concepts are yet to sink in properly haha

https://github.com/ekanime/trickbeats.git